Docker build failing due to 401 from an npm package on ElasticBeanstalk
I have this docker file for a nodejs express app:
FROM node:lts-alpine3.20
RUN echo $(node -v)
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/
ENV CI_GITHUB_TOKEN=my_github_token_hardcoded_directly
RUN echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${CI_GITHUB_TOKEN}" > ~/.npmrc
RUN npm i
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm", "start"]

When I run it locally via cmd docker build . it works. But when I run it on my ElasticBeanstalk app it fails with an error: "401 Unauthorized - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/SOME_PRIVATE_REPO - unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided."
No idea how this is possible, that's the whole reason I hardcoded the github_token into the DockerFile, so that I don't need to mess around with ENV's and all that. (I'll worry about the security implications later)
Any ideas?

To debug you could add a statement to your containerfile to RUN more ~/.npmrc to ensure that the file is created as expected and add appropriate debugging to npm i (perhaps npm i --verbose) to observe the HTTP calls made and whether they correctly reflect your GitHub token. It's possible (!?) that AWS is filtering auth tokens from calls to protect you from yourself but I'd expect you to be notified if this were happening.

Are you building the container locally and then running it locally (works) and remotely (fails)? It's unclear. Please include sanitized logs from the AWS build|run as appropriate.
